# Cannot Connect To PostgreSQL Database

Tags: r, database, postgresql

I am trying to connect to my database through R, but am getting an error. My coworker connects perfectly with the same exact script. Anyone know what else could be the problem? We have the same packages installed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL servers control who they listen and talk too. You did well comparing the same script between machines, but you may be coming from different subnets, or any other difference which would tickle this behaviour.

On my box, this is controlled by the file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` -- hba stands for host-based access.

So you may have to talk to your DBA or sysadmin.

Comment: The database is hosted on Heroku. Would I have to contact them?

Comment: Is the database public for all to access? Are you and your coworker trying to connect from the same port?

Comment: Try to see of you can connect via the `psql` command-line tool. RPostgreSQL uses the same underlying libraries.  If the one works, the other likely does too.

Comment: The database is not public and it is password protected. We are trying to connect through the same port. @the_darkside

Comment: I was able to connect via the psql command-line tool. @DirkEddelbuettel